# Запятая в выражении "Для дома для семьи"

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему в выражении "Для дома для семьи" не стоит запятая? По крайней мере, так было написано на купленной мною книге.

Comment: Возьмите ручку и дорисуйте зпт ))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта конструкция может считаться устойчиввм выражением. В этом случае запятая не ставится. Если не ошибаюсь, обычно так и поступают.